# Is it possible to programmatically obtain bandwith actual usage from a Zyxel-P660HW-D1 DSL router?

Tags: router

> This question comes from a similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644047/how-can-i-parse-grep-awk-etc-data-on-interactive-menu-style-text-interface)

I have a couple of old **Zyxel-P660HW-D1** DSL router devices, and would like to make some script to obtain the actual **bandwith** ussage.
But this device features a management text console options-based:

```
               Copyright (c) 1994 - 2010 ZyXEL Communications Corp.

                          P-660HW-D1 Main Menu

 Getting Started                      Advanced Management
   1. General Setup                     21. Filter Set Configuration
   2. WAN Backup Setup                  22. SNMP Configuration
   3. LAN Setup                         23. System Security
   4. Internet Access Setup             24. System Maintenance
                                        25. IP Routing Policy Setup
 Advanced Applications                  26. Schedule Setup
   11. Remote Node Setup
   12. Static Routing Setup
   14. Dial-in User Setup               99. Exit
   15. NAT Setup

                      Enter Menu Selection Number:
```

... and, even when it has some (very) rudimentary (not linux) **shell** embedded, I can not figure how to obtain these data:

- Actual **download bandwidth** ussage.
- Actual **upload bandwidth** ussage.

KBs/second (whether be it bits or bytes) would be fine. Percent of total would enough too.

Can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse (grep, awk... etc) data on interactive menu-style text interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644047/how-can-i-parse-grep-awk-etc-data-on-interactive-menu-style-text-interface)

Comment: Unless or until you put information in your question about *some other* means of interacting with the device, this is just a duplicate of your existing question - or else, arguably off topic as it concerns the use/capabilities of networking gear rather than software development.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : the other question deals about parsing data (any data, whatever) from any text menu-style interface, showing the Zyxel model and proposing the bandwith just as an **example**: any other data or any other menu-style text interface would answer that other question. This question refers specifically to the creation of a script to obtain the bandwith data from that model, maybe using some undocumented shell (yes, this router has a rather hidden and minimal shell), maybe accesing some port (many routers have a management network port). Moving to Server Fault would fit, maybe?

Comment: "maybe some undocumented" is not going to be a fit anywhere in the SE system of sites.  It's up to you to figure out if there is such a mechanism.  Otherwise, you might try to find a forum (which the SE sites are not) for users of this network device.